# Store positioning data before animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate a DIV with jQuery's `animate()`, load new content via ajax and animate back to the original position. To animate later back, I'm storing the left position via `data()`.

That's the code so far:

```
(function($){
    //Transition Out
$.fn.ajaxTransitionOut = function() {
    var origin = this.css('left');      
    var amount = $(window).width()*-1;

    return $(this).data('origin',origin).stop().animate({left:amount, opacity:0}, 400);

};

})(jQuery);
```

second try:

```
(function($){
    //Transition Out
$.fn.ajaxTransitionOut = function() {
    var origin = $(this).css('left');
    $(this).data('origin',origin)       
    var amount = $(window).width()*-1;

    return $(this).data('origin',origin).stop().animate({left:amount, opacity:0}, 400);

};

})(jQuery);
```

Problem: storing of the old position is too slow and in data 'origin' is a value while animating the Object. (Any minus-value)

If I delay the animation the right value is stored, but that's not what I want.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could insert an empty tag in the DOM before you add more data. Give each of these a unique ID and now you know all of the places in the document where "new data" begins.

Comment: This seems a little fishy. Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: thank you for your answers... I found it out. I called the function two times :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you use load instead, you can fire a function once the load has finished. Moreover, using ajax you also have options such as before, success and complete. This is the load example from the docs.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answers... I found it out. I called the function two times :-(